# Rails finder that forces loading whole association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Question class has_many Choices. I need to find a choice by some attribute value (usually id).

To clarify: parent record (question) is passed around different objects and methods and they search for children using different attributes and values.

I could do `question.choices.find(choice_id)` but this will generate a SQL query every time.

Knowing questions usually have only a handful choices and that there will be many different searches on one parent record, I suspect it will be cheaper to load whole association and search in Ruby:

```
question.choices.detect{|choice| choice.id == some_choice_id}
```

Detect comes from Enumerable and forces Rails to load the association on first call (and use cached data on future searches). This also plays nicely with eager loading: I can do Question.all(include: choices) and will whole tree loaded with two queries and then searching is very fast. It doesn't read very well though.

It gets even more hairy if I want to simulate find! behaviour:

```
question.choices.detect{|choice| choice.id == choice_id} or raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new
```

*This does exactly what I want, I'm just looking for better syntax.*

Does Rails provide some sort of dynamic finders that behave this way (force loading of whole association on first query and then search this preloaded set)?

Comment: I would keep the `find`. A database is exactly made for these kinds of tasks, while ruby is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I'm missing something baked in Rails or available in popular gem. If this is not the case, I'll just roll my own helpers:

```
Enumerable.module_eval do
  def select_by(attribute_name, value)
    detect do |item|
      item.send(attribute_name) == value
    end
  end

  def select_by!(attribute_name, value)
    select_by(attribute_name, value) \
      or raise StandardError.new("can't find item with #{attribute_name} equal to #{value} in #{self.inspect}")
  end
end
```

Usage would be:

```
question.choices.select_by(:id, 7)
user.question.select_by(:name, "Is it shiny?")
```

Comment: Nooo!  :-).  Unless I am missing something, what you want is baked in -- and quite delicious, too.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is referred to as "eager loading", and is implemented using the `.includes` method.

```
@questions = Question.includes(:choices).all
```

Will result in a query that does an inner join, returning both the questions, and each of its choices.  This assumes you have declared the relationships in your models.  Presumably you'll qualify this will some where clause instead of `.all`.

Comment: So when I have questions with choices, I still have to find ones with attribute values I'm looking for and raise exceptions if I don't find them. Yes, I do want eager-loading (see the question) but I'm looking for effective way to search eager-loaded tree without hitting DB every time.

Comment: Oops, my bad, didn't read the question carefully enough.  Eager loading is the right way to reduce the number of SQL queries, as you say, but it's not clear to me why you couldn't filter with  `.joins` and `.where` to find the ones you want (or don't want).

Comment: Right. I don't know all the searches and conditions beforehand. Different collaborator objects may ask for different choices. I updated the question - thanks for pointing this out.